# Crash issue with onClickListener

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

```
10-07 20:12:34.055 10098 10098 W   dalvikvm                                     threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c68930)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Darth377Apps.FrenchCommands/com.Darth377Apps.FrenchCommands.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.Darth377Apps.FrenchCommands.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-07 20:12:34.062 10098 10098 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 11 more    Catalog:
```

gob1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
                }
            });
        gob2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    //setContentView(R.layout.main);//change to play when finished
                }
            });
        lb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    //setContentView(R.layout.learn);
                }
            });
        plb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    //setContentView(R.layout.main);//change to play
                }
            });
        prb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    //setContentView(R.layout.main);//change to project
                }
            });I have identified an issue in the app I have been developing.
```

Every time I would open the app, it would crash with a runtime error.

I have narrowed down the code to find the part causing the crash
Note that it crashed with and without the setContentView line.

Comment: Oh, and sorry about the misformatting of the line 'gob1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){' as well as ''I have identified an issue in the app I have been developing"

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error? Which line specifically is it complaining about?

Comment: It's not advisable at all to call `setContentView` more than once except for when setting the layout during your `onCreate` Method. Why not make a new activity with that layout?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.Darth377Apps.FrenchCommands.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)

Comment: MainActivity.java:28 which one is that line

Comment: It seems it is a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: gob1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ @Mike

Comment: Can you post your onCreate method?

Comment: That means that you haven't actually assigned gob1 to anything at that point in the code yet. What is gob1? is it a button? where did you write its value?

Comment: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
   gob1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gameoverButton1);
   gob2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gameoverButton2);
   //final Button gorb1 = ()findViewById(rgorb1);
   //final Button gotv1 = (Button)findViewById(rgotv1);
   lb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.learnbtn);
   plb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
   prb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.projectbtn);`

Comment: Not here, post your whole onCreate in your post. edit it in.

Comment: gob1 is a button. It is assigned as Button gob1; before the on create and then gob1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gameoverButton1);

Comment: does your main.xml layout file contain the button with the right id?

Comment: gob1's id is defined in another XML file, game over.XML

Comment: There's your problem, I'll write my answer soon. You can't assign a button when you didn't load the proper xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` method, make sure that you set the proper layout file that contains the button that you want to attach an onClickListener to. Do something like:

```
Button button1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    gob1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gameoverButton1);
}
```

Now, you have to make sure that `gameoverButton1` is in your `main.xml` file. The way `setContentView` works is that it loads the xml file as the layout for the activity. Once loaded, you can only assign the buttons/textViews/editTexts in `main.xml`, if `gameoverButton1` is NOT in that xml file, then Android won't see that button and fail to initialize `gob1`, further calls on `gob1` will give a `nullPointerException` since `gob1` was not initialized properly. You can only use the views that are in the xml file that you loaded in your `setContentView` method. You can't load a certain xml file as your layout and then decide to create buttons and assign those buttons ids from a different xml file.

Why are you setting the layout by calling `setContentView` depending on which button is clicked? It is not advisable to call `setContentView` for more than once. `setContentView` is called in your `onCreate()` method to set the layout. Calling it again to load a new layout altogether will invalidate any button/textView/editText assignment you did since those views will cease to exist when you change your layout.

What you can do instead is to create a new activity for each new layout you have and do something like:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View p1)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivity.java);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
});
```

Do not resort to changing the layout of the current activity. Instead, create a new activity and open that activity which contains the new layout.